# trigger on change textarea value when value set with settimeout

Tags: php, jquery, events, textarea, onchange

```
$("textarea").on("change",function(){
    console.log("changed");
});
```

Now if I change value of textarea using this code

```
setTimeout(function(){$("textarea").val("13")},2000);
```

Then on change event will not be trigger, is there any way to detect this change in textarea.

Answer (score 1):

After you set it you can manually trigger it with

```
$("textarea").trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $("textarea").val("13").trigger("change")
},2000);
```